# iads in uitabbarcontroller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, iad

I have a UITabBarController like this:

[image]

I want iads to be displayed right above the tab bar throughout the app. Rather than adding iads to individual view controller (there are like 15-20 view controller), is there a way I can add it to the tab bar itself once, and it will be displayed on top of the tab bar in every view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out the TabbedBanner project in the Apple sample code [iAdSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html)?

Answer (score 0):

create a separate view controller similar to mentioned in Example [iAdsuit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html)

Try to pass your tab bar controller to banner view controller by

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[BannerViewController alloc]initWithContentViewController:tabBarController];
```